# Macro perform integer arithmetic

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to perform arithmetic (multiplication for my case) using macros?

I understand that writing a macro like:

```
#define mult(a,b) ((a)*(b))
```

Will substitute the product everywhere. But I have both my parameters as constants. I know the compiler will also perform the multiplication statically, but the issue is that I have to convert the result to a string using #.

Any idea how it can be done?

Also if it can be done with C++ macros, I am still okay. I can write those particular modules in C++ and link it up.

Following is my present code

```
#define ARG_COPY()      __asm__("subq   $8, %rsp"); \
                        __asm__("movq   %gs:0xe8, %r10"); \
                        __asm__("movq   $16, %r11"); \
                        __asm__("1:"); \
                        __asm__("movq   -8(%r10, %r11, 8), %rax"); \
                        __asm__("pushq  %rax"); \
                        __asm__("decq   %r11"); \
                        __asm__("jne    1b"); \

#define ARG_REMOVE()    __asm__("add    $136, %rsp");
```

Now the above code is written without arguments - the 136 is 16 * 8 + 8. I want to make that 16 a parameter. The same 16 is used in the first macro too.

Comment: For such cases, we use text-processing (mostly awk) to create C/C++ sources out of text (mostly tab separated files edited with spread sheet appl.) This simplifies maintenance of sources. Debugging (if necessary) is in C/C++ as usual. Thanks to CMake (and the efforts of my colleague), we could include the awk pre-processing into our build chain - it even works fine in Visual Studio. (I never recognized any dependency resolving issues with these text files.) This is neither elegant nor sophisticated but very robust and easy to handle.

Comment: @Scheff I am already using `python` to generate some assembly files. I will do the same in this case too. Just wanted to avoid creating another file format just to provide these constants. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: If you are always multiplying some number by `8` (a power of `2`), why not something like `#define mul8(a) ((a) << 3)`? Then for `unsigned` values 0-15, the multiplication works fine without risk of overflow.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin But I have to use it inside a string. I have to convert the result to a string using the ## operator. If I use that on what you mentioned, I will get `"((7) << 3)"`. That wont work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The C preprocessor operates purely on tokens (by replacing one token sequence with another). It does not do arithmetic in between.

You would have to write your own kind of preprocessor for this. Or what about creating header file with the product strings and #including it where needed? Yet another possibility: don't bother; if it's not truly a performance bottleneck, use `sprintf(s, "%d", mult(a,b));`. Maybe some compiler *is* smart enough to evaluate this at compile time.

How many constant product strings do you have? How many of them are different?

Comment: Yes, so I have to multiply one parameter with 8 always. And the possible values of the parameter can be like 0-15. I understand I can write macros like mult_0, mult_15 and call them from mult. I was just hoping for something better.

Comment: `sprintf(s, "%d", mult(a,b))` wont work. Since I have to use the string inside __asm__ intrinsic. The intrinsic won't take a variable `s`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya What about this preprocessor then: `sed 's/mult(15,8)/"120"/g' file.c` for each product.

Comment: if I have to do this, I would rather just do `#define mult(a) mult_##a` and define from mult_0 to mult_15.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya This seems like an awful lot of trouble to "refactor" sixteen named strings. `char const str_8x0[] = "0", str_8x1[] = "8", str_8x2[] = "16"` etc, right? Why should the preprocessor be used at all?

Comment: @Jens Also `mult(15,8)` wont appear directly for sed to work. It is generated by other macros.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Are you in control of the program generating the mult statements? Then I would fix the problem at the source instead of patching over it.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I have to use the string inside an inline assembly intrinsic `__asm__`. I am not sure the compiler would accept a `const char[]` there

Comment: @Jens - I will explain in detail. I have a macro called `ARG_COPY(x)` which I call from multiple places. Inside the ARG_COPY I have to use x*4 and x*8 + constant as a string inside `__asm__`. I will edit my question to show the entire scenario.

Comment: Why aren't you sure the `__asm__` intrinisc won't accept a `const char*`? IT would seem to me to be the work of a minute or two to find out.

Comment: The preprocessor does do arithmetic, e.g. `#if 2 + 2 == 4` is valid.

Comment: @M.M That's neither in token replacement, nor *in between* token expansions.

Comment: @JeremyP I checked it and - `error: expected string literal in 'asm'` Also I won't be able to combine it with rest of my argument to asm. Anyway, I will go ahead and write multiple `mult_x` macros.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to perform arithmetic (multiplication for my case) using macros?

[Yes,](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f322ff2fb6fb3fd1) given the restrictions you specified (that you're using constants; in particular, decimal literals), and with restrictions. The linked to code shows an ADD and a MUL macro that does just this (it's a bit too big to just paste inline).  To do this with a preprocessor macro per se requires "implementing arithmetic". This example only supports numbers from 1 to 255, and requires your C99 compliant preprocessor support 511 arguments.

The [Boost preprocessor library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) also contains an implementation of macro arithmetic; and has code supporting DIV and SUB.